# how to create a script shell command

Tags: bash, monitoring, sudo, awstats, cpan

Hi evry one can someone help me to get this command with scrit shell ?

```
root@VPS:/work# cpan
Loading internal logger. Log::Log4perl recommended for better logging

CPAN.pm requires configuration, but most of it can be done automatically.
If you answer 'no' below, you will enter an interactive dialog for each
configuration option instead.

Would you like to configure as much as possible automatically? [yes] yes


Autoconfiguration complete.

commit: wrote '/root/.cpan/CPAN/MyConfig.pm'

You can re-run configuration any time with 'o conf init' in the CPAN shell
Terminal does not support AddHistory.

To fix enter>  install Term::ReadLine::Perl


cpan shell -- CPAN exploration and modules installation (v2.22)
Enter 'h' for help.

cpan[1]>install Geo::IP
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

From [CPAN documentation](http://www.cpan.org/modules/INSTALL.html) you can install a module with this generic syntax:

```
cpan module_name [ module_name ... ]
```

In your case:

```
cpan Geo::IP
```